# Make vlookup VBA to search through all available sheet on workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

how can I make Vlookup search all the available sheets in my workbook? The number of my sheets not always the same

here's the code I use but still found error on it

```
sub lookup()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet
Dim DepSheet As Worksheet
Dim form As String
Dim startcell As Range
Dim thiswb As Workbook

Set MasterSheet = Sheets("Recap")
Set DepSheet = Sheets("Depreciation")
Set startcell = MasterSheet.Range("C6")
Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In thiswb
If Not ws.Name = MasterSheet.Name And Not ws.Name = DepSheet.Name Then
startcell.form = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MasterSheet.Range("C6"), ws.Range("E6:E2000"), 4, False)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
startcell.form = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MasterSheet.Range("C6"), ws.Range("E6:E2000"), 2, False)
End If
End If

Next ws
end sub
```

this is the old code of the index match that I always ask the unavailable sheet from the formula.

```
'COA
Sheets(2).Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX('ACF'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'ACF'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('ACF'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'ACF'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('BIGBIKE'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('BIGBIKE'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('BOD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BOD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('BOD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BOD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('CORPSEC'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('CORPSEC'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('DIGITAL'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('DIGITAL'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('GDG'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'GDG'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('GDG'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'GDG'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('HC3'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HC3'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('HC3'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HC3'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('HRGA'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('HRGA'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('IT'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'IT'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('IT'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'IT'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('LDD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'LDD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('LDD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'LDD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('MCD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MCD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('MCD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MCD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('MSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MSD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('MSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MSD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('NPD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'NPD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('NPD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'NPD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('PARTS'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('PARTS'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('PURCHASING'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('PURCHASING'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('TSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'TSD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),INDEX('TSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'TSD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"
```

this is the old code for the vlookup that I use before and excel always ask for the unavailable sheet to be updated.

```
'Status
Sheets(2).Range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'ACF'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'ACF'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'BOD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'BOD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'GDG'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'GDG'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'HC3'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'HC3'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'IT'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'IT'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'LDD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'LDD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'MCD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'MCD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'MSD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'MSD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'NPD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'NPD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'TSD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),VLOOKUP(RC3,'TSD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"
```

Comment: What do you expect from `startcell.form`? Where do you want returning the `Vlookup` result?

Comment: @FaneDuru its the first cell that contain the formula but seems that I mistype it (should be on E6)

Comment: A `form` property does not exist for a range, as a `Cell` is... Then, are there only an occurrence in all the sheets? Otherwise, everything will  be overwritten... Can you better explain **in words** what you try accomplishing? Do you search for a `Vlookup` return in all sheets and it should be place in the range "E6", overwriting all existing values? Practically, the result there will  be the one of **the last iterated sheet**...

Comment: what I want to achieve is that I want to run vlookup and index match formula, but the formula I type on my code is basically copied from recording macro and it included all the sheets. The problem is that the sheet that supposes to be searched is not always there, sometimes only 5 or 7 out of 16 sheets. Each time I run my code, excel always asks me to update the value of the unavailable sheet on the workbook. I edited my question by adding the old code.

Comment: I start thinking that I am wasting my time, no offence...

Comment: @FaneDuru sorry for my strange question, its just that if we use vlookup formula, we need to define each sheet in which were the lookup value located. what I want to achieve is that I don't want to define the sheet, instead just lookup the value through the sheets that are available on the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sub to loop through all sheets.
You then need to define which sheets are which. You may want to start the loop at 3 if 1 & 2 are static sheets "Recap" and "Depreciation".

```
      Sub WorksheetLoop()

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count

            ' Insert your code here.
            ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
            ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
            MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

         Next I

      End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way. `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` returns a fatal error, but `Application.VLookup` does not. Not understanding where you want returning, the adapted code only writes in `Immediate Window` the `Vlookup` result for each sheet. In order to see the return, use `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor):

```
Sub lookup()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, MasterSheet As Worksheet
 Dim startcell As Range, thiswb As Workbook
 Dim result As Variant, retCell as range

 Set MasterSheet = Sheets("Recap")
 Set startcell = MasterSheet.Range("C6")
 Set retCell = MasterSheet.Range("E6") 'the cell where to return
 Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook

 For Each ws In thiswb.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Recap" And ws.Name <> "Depreciation" Then
        result = Application.VLookup(startcell.value, ws.Range("E6:E2000"), 4, False)
        
        If IsError(result) Then
            result = Application.VLookup(startcell.value, ws.Range("E6:E2000"), 2, False)
        End If
        Debug.Print ws.Name, result
        if not iserror(result) then retCell.Value = result 'as stated in your comment...
    End If
 Next ws
End Sub
```

Your question is a little strange, in terms of returning way. If the code will work using yours as model, the result will be the `Vlookup` result of **only the last sheet**. Even if is `#N/A`(not a match)...

The above code returns **the last occurrence, if many** of the `Vlookup` result, which is not `#N/A`. `Error 2042` means that `Vlookup` did not find a match. The equivalent of `#N/A`...

Comment: what I want is to simplify my old code and also to run only on the available sheet on the workbook. If I use the old code, excel always gives me a pop-up that asks me to update the unavailable sheet inside the workbook. For example, if ACF sheet is not available then excel will ask me to select the update file. And what I want is that the vlookup function search on all sheets that are available in the workbook.

Comment: also, could you explain to me what this line do?
`Debug.Print ws.Name, result
        if not iserror(result) then retCell.Value = result 'as stated in your comment...`

Comment: @TheLSD There are two lines. About the first one, it is written in my answer: "**code only writes in `Immediate Window` the `Vlookup` result for each sheet. In order to see the return, use `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor)**". Is it still unclear? The second line, writes in "E6" the `Vlookup` return **only if a match exists**. But, if more then one such matching occurrences exist, the next one will overwrite the previous. Your question is not clear at all, on my taste... I specifically asked about many occurrences and you did not answer anything...

Answer (score 0):

I think this UDF is close to what you want to do - enter (eg) `=GetLookup(C6)` where you want the result to show.

```vb
Function GetLookup(v)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, m, rv
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Recap" And ws.Name <> "Depreciation" Then   'skip these sheets
            m = Application.Match(v, ws.Range("C6:C2000"), 0)                    'col C match?
            If IsError(m) Then m = Application.Match(v, ws.Range("E6:E2000"), 0) 'col E match?
            If Not IsError(m) Then               'got a match
                GetLookup = ws.Range("A6:A2000").Cells(m) 'fix range if needed
                Exit Function                    'done searching
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    GetLookup = "???" 'or whatever ("no match" result)
End Function
```